# eclipse plugin development-adding button to toolbar and its behaviour

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Using `eclipse plugin`, I am trying to add some buttons in toolbar and want to perform some action `onclick` to that button.

so what i did in extension tab i added **org.eclipse.ui.menus** and so added a menucontribution to it with **URI location- toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar**.And then a toolbar in it with a **command lets say Design**

so by doing this a got a button on toolbar with name Design.
now i want it should be clickable (as for now it is inactive) and on click i can add some behavior/action to it.

please help.

Comment: Have you added a Handler for your command id?

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Hello,World Command"  plug-in template which adds a "Sample Menu" in the toolbar and start from that point.